# Query out a specific date regardless of the time, using python

Tags: arcpy, select, date, format

Problem: I have a feature class with an attribute table with a field called Edited_Date and its data in the field is as follows: 4/8/2015 10:00:00 PM. I want to select all records that are Edited_Date is 4/8/2015 regardless of the time of day. SO I want to use a wildcard to substitute the hour minutes seconds and PM.

I run the following code using python to select records by Edited_Date but no records are being selected. I've tried different formats but none is working and I can't find the proper syntax to query pout a date such as

Code:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Plant_Layer", "NEW_SELECTION", " [last_edited_date] = '4/8/2015' + '%s' ")
```

What is the syntax to do this in Python? Select a date regardless of the time.

Comment: Why not > yesterday and < tomorrow? Is it a date field or a string field containing date information?

Comment: The field in the attribute table is DATE. The problem is that the field includes hour:minutes:seconds PM, which is causing the problem.

Comment: If you know the query date then take of one day (yesterday), add one day (tomorrow) and then select *last_edited_date > yesterday and last_edited_date < tomorrow*. That way the hours and minutes don't matter as much. Ensure that yesterday is 11:59:59pm and tomorrow is 00:00:01am.

Comment: Great stuff Michael, I didn't think of that before. I just used the last_edited_date > yesterday and last_edited_date < tomorrow and it worked. I got the selected records. Aaah, been looking at the screen too long! I used the following.... [last_edited_date] > '4/8/2015' and [last_edited_date] < '4/9/2015' ....and Bingo! Thanks Michael.

Comment: Now one more step..is that I'm using parameters..but getting error with syntax: I have the following:

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("TreeDatabase_Layer", "NEW_SELECTION", "[last_edited_date] >" + getdate1 and "[last_edited_date] <" + getdate2)

Comment: "[last_edited_date] > " + getdate1 + " and [last_edited_date] < " + getdate2... it's nice to have spaces, the problem was the *and* was missing + and was looking for a variable called 'and' as it wasn't in the string. With queries you can skip the [] around the variables - it's more likely to cause problems as it changes depending on data type and syntax parser.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I tried the following and added the + like you said. It finally works!! ---> "[last_edited_date]>" + " ' " + date1 + " ' " + "and" + "[last_edited_date]<" + " ' " + date2 +" ' "

Your help is much appreciated..and you're really good at this. I'm still in the learning stage with Python and GIS

Comment: I've been doing this since 1992, I've picked up a few things along the way.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson - add your (clever) solution as an answer, please!